# WHM - add another user account via SSH

Tags: ssh, unix

I'm working for a crowd that have 'misplaced' the password for their WHM root login but I'm able to SSH to the server using the key file they've provided. I CAN'T change the password for root as they are concerned other functions are using it (and people possibly).

Is there any way so I can add another user account on the server that I can then use via the WHM login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give up and change the system root password.

WHM will allow a root login with the system root password, and if neither you nor the client actually knows it, you are going to have to reset the password anyway. You simply cannot avoid this without also avoiding doing any actual work, which defeats the purpose.

As for other processes using the root password, that seems unlikely, as even the most junior of admins will typically resist hard-coding any root password anywhere. People, on the other hand, might, and you can simply deal with them if they complain.

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing